# How to disable scroll overflow x in iOS with CSS

Tags: html, ios, css, overflow, viewport

I have website that works well if opened in desktops and android device, but when I open in iOS devices such as Iphone and Ipad, the background did not fixed like on other devices, it will expand the background and create blank space on the right side of the page, and I used `user-scalable=no` to make user cant scrolling to the blank space, but still not works. Actually, I already use `overflow-x: hidden;` but my navbar didnt work like usual, the `href` didnt go to the target id. For example, `<a href="#news">news</a></li>` it should go to the div id news, but it go randomly. So, what I should I use to prevent user to scroll in iOS?

this is the example of the blank space in iOS:

[image: the page]
[image: the blank space]

Answer (score 0):

iOS safari has it's own set of issues. It generally tends to ignore all overflow: hidden you give on body and html. The only solution that i found till now was to either make you body exactly the size of your viewport and scroll the content within, or just make the position of the body fixed, in case your background is scrolling when you have a floating content on top that you want to scroll.

Comment: can u give an example? maybe how I make the body exactly the size of Iphone 5 if user opened with iphone 5? thanks

Comment: max-height: 100vh; max-width: 100vw;

Comment: its on body or viewport? its still can scroll to the right side

Comment: give the style to the body so that the whole page does not move. Inside the body the overflow-x: hidden; should work

Comment: but like I said at my question, I already use overflow x hidden but then my navbar didnt work well :( dunno why

Comment: @wrick17 this `max-height: 100vh; max-width: 100vw;` should be in the answer.